# Remplazo caracter PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Necesito remplazar un carácter en particular de una cada en oracle.

Por ejemplo:

```
cadena= '12121113'
```

y lo que necesito es cambiar el "1" por un "2" pero solo el "1" que esta en la posición 3.

y devolverme el resultado modificado.

Como resultado debería queda `'12221113'`.

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: ¿quieres cambiar el valor sólo si es un 1?¿O no importa el carácter que sea se reemplazará por un 2?

Comment: Consulta si yo quiero reemplazar a partir del segundo numero repitido por 2, como tendria que hacer cadena:12121113 resultado: 12222223

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esta consulta que se verá en la tercera "caso cuando" el valor es igual a 1.

[SUBSTR functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm)

Si el resultado es verdadero, entonces se concatena la primera parte de la subcadena, despues a ser concatenado parte que se va a cambiar y luego se concatena con el final de su string.

Si es falso, entonces se devolverá el valor verdadero.

```
select 
case when substr('12121113', 3, 1) = 1
  then substr('12121113', 1, 2) || replace(substr('12121113', 3, 1), '1', '2') || substr('12121113', 4)
  else '12121113'
end as modified
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

como alternativa te dejo el siguiente código.
puedes hacer uso de instr

```
 instr('12121113','1',2)
```

y la consulta seria la siguiente

```
select substr('12121113',1,instr('12121113','1',2)-1)||
    replace(substr('12121113',instr('12121113','1',2),1),'1','2')||
    substr('12121113',instr('12121113','1',2)+1,length(12121113))
from dual
```

Comment: El problema de este select Osmar es que si el tercer carácter es 2, entonces esta función reemplaza al siguiente 1 y solo se quiere reemplazar en la posición 3 del string.

Answer (score 0):

Ruben

Esta forma es más corta que las anteriores, pero la clave esta en las expresiones regulares, estoy seguro que debe haber una solución aún más corta con una sola expresión regular.

```
SELECT 
SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE('12121113','1','2',3,1),1,3) || SUBSTR('12121113',4)
FROM DUAL;
```

> Resultado: 12221113